# R - sum vectors matching names

Tags: r, rowsum

I need to sum columns of a table that have a names starting with a particular string.

An example table might be:

```
tbl<-data.frame(num1=c(3,2,9), num2=c(3,2,9),n3=c(3,2,9),char1=c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

I get the list of columns (in this example I wrote only 2, but the real case has more tan 20).

```
a<-colnames(tbl)[grep('num', colnames(tbl))]
```

I tried with

```
sum(tbl[,a])
```

But I get only one number with the total sum of the elements in both vectors.

What I need is the result of:

```
tbl$num1+ tbl$num2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can either use `Reduce`

```
 Reduce(`+`, tbl[a])
```

Or `rowSums`.  The `rowSums` also has the option of removing the NA elements with `na.rm=TRUE`.

```
rowSums(tbl[a])
```